# How is PCA is different from SubSpace clustering and how do we extract variables responsible for the first PCA component?

Tags: clustering, visualization, pca

**New update:**

I understand PCA components ensure we select variables responsible for high variance, but I would like to know how to extract key variables responsible only for high variance through PCA components.

Ideally, a simple example would help.

This is my code:

```
#Implementing PCA for visualizing after Kmeans clustering

`# Interpret 3 cluster solution
model3=KMeans(n_clusters=3)
model3.fit(clus_train)
clusassign=model3.predict(clus_train)
# plot clusters
```

> '''The new variables, called canonical variables, are ordered in terms
>   of the proportion of variance and the clustering variables that is
>   accounted for by each of the canonical variables.  So the first
>   canonical variable will count for the largest proportion of the
>   variance. The second canonical variable will account for the next
>   largest proportion of variance, and so on. Usually, the majority of
>   the variance in the clustering variables will be accounted for by the
>   first couple of canonical variables and those are the variables that
>   we can plot. '''

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca_2 = PCA(2) # Selecting 2 components
plot_columns = pca_2.fit_transform(clus_train)
plt.scatter(x=plot_columns[:,0], y=plot_columns[:,1], c=model3.labels_,)
```

Observations are more spread out indicating less correlation among the
 observations and higher within cluster variance.

```
plt.xlabel('Canonical variable 1')
plt.ylabel('Canonical variable 2')
plt.title('Scatterplot of Canonical Variables for 3 Clusters')
plt.show()`
```

Comment: Many advantages, like collapsing correlated variables...

Comment: Thanks Student for insights. Can you give an example illustration where I can undertstand what you mean...
Because After getting PCA components, I used it only for visualizing. I would like to know how this can be used for collasing correlated variables?

Actually I was using correlation function before clustering itself, So your suggestion would eliminate that redundency in my code

Comment: Please, **learn the markdown format** (use the help button) to make your question *readable*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the dimensionality of a dataset with PCA does not only benefits humans trying to look at the data in a graspable number of dimensions. It is also useful for machine learning algorithms to be trained on a subset of dimensions. Both to reduce the complexity of the data and the computational cost of training such machine learning model.

Comment: Thanks Tony for insights. Can you give an example illustration where I can undertstand what you mean...
Because After getting PCA components, I used it only for visualizing. I would like to know how this can be used for reducing complexity ?

Comment: Check this out: http://jotterbach.github.io/2016/03/24/Principal_Component_Analysis/ and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#decompositions for some examples

Comment: Thanks Tony for an understandable example.
I tried to execute...    tl.set_color(plot1[0].get_color())
seems to give an error

NameError: name 'plot1' is not defined

I am using python 3.5 on spyder

Answer (score 0):

PCA is a very common technique, so you might want to google around. PCA is awfully common for data visualisation, but it has many other uses.

For instance, if you want to fit a linear regression on average income. Now, you have collected 500+ predictors, but lots of them are correlated like:

- How much the person pays tax last year
- How much the person pays tax the year before
- How much the person pays tax three years ago
- ....

Those predictors are highly correlated and might present modelling problems in your linear model. A very common technique is to use PCA to reduce into a set of reduced orthogonal principal components. You can then use those components for building your model.

> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22665/how-to-use-principal-components-as-predictors-in-glm